safe-core | Auth-kit SDK login not work
I am currently experiencing problems with the Auth-kit SDK product on your platform. As is well known, this product is part of your suite of tools to work with Smart Accounts. Specifically, the Auth-kit SDK allows you to generate a signer/eoa through social login. Currently I have this SDK integrated into my Dapp, but for a couple of days the social login has not been working. After extensive research on my part, I found that the error comes from you, since within yours demo apps, the social login does not work either and presents the same error that I present. Here I attach images of the error and links to your demo apps where the error also occurs.
### Links

https://safe.web3auth.com/v0/
https://safe.web3auth.com/v1/
https://safe.web3auth.com/v2/
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/auth-kit
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@web3auth/safeauth-embed?activeTab=code

### Images


thanks for reaching out about this problem. The problem comes from an update in the Web3Auth service a few weeks ago. We stopped supporting it, in favor of the SafeAuth. If you want to keep using Web3Auth with Safe (which we don't recommend), you can still use their solution directly (not through the AuthKit), however please note that the way they calculate addresses will be different. If you have existing users this may be a problem, in which case you might want to use the "Export private keys" feature. Web3Auth also require a clientId from now on.
Hope it helps. Best, Louis

hi, why do you still have web3-auth in the documentation? At least I would expect a notice about this important change. thx
